# Set Values of Vector at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, compile-time

I implemented my own vector class for education. Here is a simplified snippet:

```
template <size_t DIM>
class Vector
{
private:
    float _data[DIM];

public:
    void Set();
    float Length() const;
    float& operator[](size_t index);
}
```

I implemented the `Length()` and the `operator[]` methods successfully, my question now is how to implement the `Set()` method, which needs to take `DIM` arguments, not more and not less and is supposed to fill the vector.

I have solved this problem with the following tweak:

```
void Set(const std::array<float, DIM>& input)
{
    std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), _data);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to use the `Set()` method as follows:
`object.Set({1,2,3})` and not as follows `object.Set(1,2,3)` and additionally the compiler only complains if the amount of arguments inside `{}` is larger than `DIM` and not smaller.

I also used a second hack which solves this problem but creates another :

```
size_t index = 0;

template <typename FIRST>
void Set(FIRST first)
{
    _data[index] = first;
    index = 0;
}

template <typename FIRST, typename ... SECOND>
void Set(FIRST first, SECOND... second)
{
    _data[index] = first;
    ++index;
    Set2(second...);
}
```

Now I can use `object.Set(1,2,3)`

This however can take less or more than `DIM` arguments and thus is not a good option. I know that I can fix that by checking at run-time but I want the compiler to complain when there are not exactly DIM arguments at compile-time.
Some tips on how to improve my solutions would me nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a `static_assert`:

```
template <size_t DIM>
class Vector
{
private:
    std::array<float, DIM> data_;

public:
    // Other stuff

    template <typename... Args>
    void Set(Args... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == DIM,
                      "Wrong number of args");
        data_ = {args...};
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00ef54c2c72f9528)

If the wrong number of elements are supplied, then the static assertion will provide a nice error at compile time saying exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Why use `std::tuple_size` instead of `sizeof...`? This works fine: `static_assert(sizeof...(args) == DIM, "Wrong number of args");`

Comment: @Miles Budnek yeah, same question as Remy

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right.  For some reason I totally forgot `sizeof...` is a thing.  In my defense, I'm stuck with C++98 at work, so I rarely get to use these fancy new (now 7+ years old) features.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: I am in the same boat (my compiler at work is 16 years old!).